# How to execute two select queries at once in Postico Postgresql on Mac

Tags: sql, postgresql

I used to run my entire query in mssql which had many select statements. Each select statement created a temp table. I am trying to do the same in postgresql using Postico but it wont let me do so. I have installed Postico 3 on Mac. To execute two select statements I have to select each one and execute them separately.

```
Create Temp table tmp_SL_custNo as
select *  from SL_11_29_2016

Create Temp table tmp_SV_custNo as
select *  from SV_11_29_2016
```

Currently i have to select each create temp table query and run it separate. So to create two temp tables above i run first two lines once and then the last two lines of code. I want to be able to select the entire above code and run it once  so that two temp tables are created together. Can it be done in Postico 3?

Comment: separate them with a semicolon?

Comment: wow that was so simple ! thanks !

Answer (score 2):

add a semicolon ";" after every query and all of them will execute together.

```
Create Temp table tmp_SL_custNo as
select *  from SL_11_29_2016;

Create Temp table tmp_SV_custNo as
select *  from SV_11_29_2016;
```